# How to fetch history of data from Google analyics using C#.Net?

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics-api

My account creation in Google Analytics, tracking code implementation in my application happened at July 2014. But i need to fetch data for Jan 2014 using C#.Net. Is it possible? Possible means please give me the idea?

Comment: If you've started using it in July, where do you expect data to come from for January?

Comment: My website is running from 2012. But i registered in Google Analytics at July 2014. My client asking me to get previous history value also. Is it possible? Means pls give me u r point?

Comment: I have a child, born in 2014. Can you tell me how I can get a picture of that child from 2012?